# Scaling an image according to a scaling factor that changes continuously along an axis

Tags: python, image-processing

I am not sure how I can explain this but here goes.

I want to scale down an image, for example, along its y-axis but the scaling factor should be 1 at `y = 0` and change along the axis according to a function (`1/(y+1)` for example) so that the resulting image does not lose much detail around the initial rows and loses increasingly more detail as you move towards higher rows.

The operation should be invertible, but of course some detail would be lost at higher rows.

I feel like I can achieve this via a matrix multiplication, and revert back by multiplying the result with the transpose of the same matrix but I am not sure if that's correct, and if so, I don't know how to create such a matrix.